# Visual Studio indentation set to two spaces instead of four space tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I have just opened an old project here at work.   Someone appears to have changed the indentation.   It's set to 2 spaces instead of four space tabbing.

[image]

What I have tried:

1. I tried doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> but that hasn't changed it back to proper indentation.
2. I Deleted the `_ReSharper.Caches` directory, and a new one is just created, no change to the indentation.

When those didn't work, I have started comparing settings in my visual studio with two different solutions.

Resharper settings appear to be identical so are the settings in visual studio.

**Re-sharper settings**

[image]

**Visual studio settings**

[image]

Which makes me think this must be in one of the project files or something?  If it's not an issue with the settings in my visual studio, what's overriding the tabbing?

Of note when the project loads I swear it loads with proper indentation and then it's reformatted in the last second. Not sure it matters, but the projects are .net core 1.0 there are three projects in the solution all three appear to be affected.

Hope someone has a fix for this; it's really hard to read it like this.

Comment: Is there a `.editorconfig` file in the project directory or any parent directories?

Comment: If the indentation are spaces, there's nothing you can do to change it. Look at the file history in source control for the one to blame!

Comment: @yaakov yes there is in the solution directory

Comment: @PhillipNgan theres a lot more damaging in this project i could use for blame but said developer no longer works here.

Comment: @yaakov It was set to 2 i set them to four Cntrl + K + d works now.   But i think i am going to have to do it on every file :(  Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Visual Studio may be using an [.editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options) file in the project's directory (or in any parent directory) which allows for a consistent code style within a codebase regardless of user settings.

Visual Studio should indicate this in the lower left-hand area of the IDE window.

If this is the case, you'll need to modify `.editorconfig` and define a new style in order to change the configuration for the automatic formatting tools.

Comment: This still means i will need to reformat all the files now but great solution i have never seen that file before.   You are right about the note.  it says "User preferences for this file type are overridden by this projects coding conversions."   I didn't even notice it until you posted this.

Answer (score 16):

As people says in answers and comments this is probably a `.editorconfig`. In our case a developer started using VS Code and when upgrading to VS 2017 Visual Studio also accepts these files.

This was the value in the file that was automatically added:

```
[*]
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

By adding this we could use C# normally and the developer who wanted to use VS Code could continue to do that:

```
[*.cs]
indent_style = space 
indent_size = 4
```

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44231/cant-set-indent-level-to-4-spaces-in-vs-2017.html

Answer (score 0):

What I have just done but I am no expert, was to go to Tools>>Options. When the Options windows pops, I scroll down to Text Editor>>All Languages>>Tabs. Then, in Tab size and in Indent size, I put, in my case "3", but choose whatever number you prefer, I guess in your case, "4". By the way, if you find "2" in any of/both the cells, it is a first confirmation that it could be the right place for these settings. Please note the environment is Visual Studio 2022.